# unable to play wmv videos in mozilla and chrome

Tags: jquery, html

i am using  tag to play wmv  videos in a web page, and it works fine in IE but not in Mozilla and chrome.

i have tried using a jquery media plugin to play videos in mozilla and chrome. the path of the video specified is from local. But its not working.

Comment: why wmv? instead you can try with some other formats which most of the browser supports widely.

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

Like Jai said in te comments, thy to use another format. 
The best solution is to convert your video to multiple formats, so the chance is greater that all browsers support that video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For more information, check [w3schools](http://%3Cvideo%20width=%22320%22%20height=%22240%22%20controls%3E%20%20%20%3Csource%20src=%22movie.mp4%22%20type=%22video/mp4%22%3E%20%20%20%3Csource%20src=%22movie.ogg%22%20type=%22video/ogg%22%3E%20%20%20Your%20browser%20does%20not%20support%20the%20video%20tag.%20%3C/video%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Change the format or add a Flash Player for Compatibility to the browser.
Also note that autoplay won't work on some of the browsers like opera, safari, etc..

`<embed src=" **Link**  ">`